# Evaluate statistically if time series is Jump or Trend?

Tags: time-series, python, change-point

Q1.
Is there any statistical test to differentiate "Trend" and "Jumps". Below example.
I have tried Successive variation test (Neumann), all data sets yield same results.

It is clear that Example 1 has trend, Jumps in case of example 2 & 3.
What statistical will tell us that Example 1 has trend while other's do not.
Unfortunately will not be able to share the data, just looking for some clues.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]
[image: Example 3]

---

Q2.
How do you statistically conclude that there is trend / No trend ? |or| How do you say data is non-stationary and has a trend ?

If slope is the measure of trend, is there a threshold for slope after which we can consider that the time series has a trend ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $R^2$ (or mean squared error or mean absolute error) metric to see if the trend is really approximating the data appropriately. In the first case the performance metric should be higher (for $R^2$) or lower (for mean squared error or mean absolute error) indicating a trend in comparison to the last two cases.

Note, that trend could also imply that the series is stationary. This would be true if the slope of the linear approximation is vanishing.

Comment: $R^2$, $MSE$, and $MAE$ imply a model that makes predictions. What would that model be? $\text{//}$ You seem to be advocating for something like comparing the model metrics ($R^2$, $MSE$, and/or $MAE$) for two models, one that considers the jump and another that does not. In-sample, more complicated models (when considering nested models, which I believe is the case here) outperform relatively simple models. Perhaps you mean to say that there should be some kind of penalty for the "jump" parameter, kind of like $R^2_{adj}$ or an $F$-test of the nested models.

Comment: @Dave , I was suggested  piecewise linear regression to differentiate the two. However I am unable to identify the breakpoints (in python). Any suggestion on how to do it ? Also , what slope of regression line will tell us if there is a trend or not ?